# is complex number under absolute value a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have just started going over abstract algebra.

One of the question is

$*$ is defined on $\mathbb C$ such that $a*b=|ab|$

I tried to check three axioms : 1) Associativity 2) identity 3) inverse

I found out with long computation that Associativity works.

For identity, $a*e=e*a=a$ , where $a*e=|ae|=a$

I am quite confused how to find out the value of e, since this is a complex number.

Can anyone show me why this is a group or not a group?

Comment: Is the number 0 allowed? If so, what is its inverse?

Comment: Also, is there ever going to be anything such that $i*b = i$?  What does that mean about the potential existence of an identity?

Comment: I think 0 is allowed and if then, inverse of 0 would be any number in C. It does not make sense since identity is 0? is that what you mean chris?

Answer (score 2):

It’s *not* a group as it fails to have an identity.

*Hint*. Look at $a = -1$ and the range of the defined operation “$*$”.

Comment: if a=-1, then there is no identity e because absolute value can not be negative. is that what you mean? Also, If Identity fails, does that mean that there is no inverse?

Comment: Because third axiom says that a*b=b*a=e and we know there is no such e and therefore no b?

Comment: @jeniffer Yes, that’s what I mean. The notion of an inverse (for $a ∈ ℂ$ some element $a' ∈ ℂ$ such that $a*a' = e$ and $a'*a = e$, the identity) doesn’t make any sense if there isn’t an identity to begin with. Also note, that with the same argument the operation doesn’t even yield a group (/monoid) when restricted to $ℝ$.

Comment: And, one more thing, I found out that associativity works for this case. Is this right? I just want to make sure my long computation has no mistake

Comment: @jeniffer Not sure, why it’s that long: For $a, b, c ∈ ℂ$:
$$\begin{align*}
(a*b)*c &= |ab|*c = ||ab|·c| = |ab|·|c|\\
&= |abc|\\
&= |a|·|bc| = |a·|bc|| = a*|bc| = a*(b*c)
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

There is a theorem that if $\langle G, \ast\rangle$ is a group, then each function $f_a$ defined by $$f_a(x) = a\ast x$$ must be a bijection.  (That is, the left coset $aG$ must be equal to $G$.) For example, the function $f_3(x) = 3 + x$ is a bijection of the real numbers.

This is not hard to show.  To see that $f_a$ is onto $G$, just note that  each $y\in G$ is in the range of $f$ because $f_a(a^{-1}*y) = y$.  To see that $f_a$ is one-to-one, suppose we have $f_a(x) = f_a(x')$.  Then $a*x=a*x'$, and multiplying by $a^{-1}$ on the left we obtain $x=x'$.

Here your function $f_a(x) = |ax|$ is evidently not a bijection of the complex numbers because its value is always a positive real number.  So the operation is not a group operation.

Answer (score -1):

It is not group. Problem is with a=-s s$\in R^+$.

Comment: No, $1$ is no neutral element. Maybe I did misunderstand your answer, though?

Comment: how can e be 1 ?

Comment: It can't my mistake.

Comment: I was rewritting the answer.